# What does a pet do when it goes into living quarters?

Tags: fallout-shelter

One of my pets went into the living quarters and hid behind the wall what does that mean?

Comment: Which fallout are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

Similar to how children and pregnant women run and hide, your pets hide from combat when being attacked. It means the owner, where ever they are, was being attacked by the event that was going on.

Comment: Does this affect their bonus? For example I believe some pets give bonuses to damage, or drops from enemies. Is this still active when they hide?